# about Monit and PHP

Tags: php, linux

Excuse me, may I ask in linux, is there any way to call php code from the monitrc file of Monit?

THanks

Comment: Please elaborate. E.g do you want to check whether a php process is (still) running? Or do you want to evaluate the return value of the php script as a test? Or ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to use the following command to execute scripts:

php /full/path/to/your/script.php